# jQuery zClip not working with my appended table. Could it be a version conflict?

Tags: jquery, zclip

I tried to implement this into my project [jsFiddle zClip with appended table](http://jsfiddle.net/f4gZA/)

```
var appendTable = new String();

appendTable = '<table>';

appendTable += '<tr><th id="header">Header 1</th>';
appendTable += '<td><div id="row1">Row 1</div></td></tr>';
appendTable += '<tr><th id="header">Header 2</th><td id="row2">Row 2</td></tr>';
appendTable += '<tr><th id="header">Header 3</th><td><div>';
appendTable += '<div id="row3">This will be copied!</div>';
appendTable += '<button id="copyRow3">Copy</button>';
appendTable += '</div></td></tr>';

appendTable += '</table>';

$('#appendTable').append(appendTable);

$("#copyRow3").zclip({
   path: "http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/ZeroClipboard.swf",
   copy: function() { return $('#row3').text(); }
});
```

This fiddle should be working, but when implement it, it doesn't work at all.  It never copies the designated div.

jquery-1.4.1.min.js is the jquery file I'm using with jquery.zclip.min.js.  Would this be the reason why zClip is not working?

Also just incase I tried to include a copy button in the html and when clicked it seemed like my browser froze.

Comment: Your jsFiddle works. When I implement the code you posted above on jsFiddle, and specify jQuery 1.4.1 minified (taken from Google's CDN — check the 'External Resources' panel, [it still works](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/quYvv/). If your implementation outside of jsFiddle isn't working, are there any errors that come up in your Javascript console? Do all your browsers freeze?

Comment: There are no errors in the console, I'm currently using Firefox with firebug.  If I take the button in the appended table out and put it in the html, my browser freezes.  I have not try Chrome or IE yet.

Comment: Try them! Why are you taking the button out of the appended table? Does it produce different results if you leave it in?

Comment: I believed that being in the appended table was the reason why the copy button was not working.  This is the only reason why I tried removing it and placing it in the html, I found out then that it did not matter.

Comment: Ah OK. So does Firefox also freeze when you try [the jsFiddle I linked](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/quYvv/)? And do Chrome and IE freeze or show errors?

Comment: Yes I did try them, and no it is still not working.  I really dont understand why it isnt working.  I've been stuck on this for almost a whole day now.  I really can't spend anymore time on this...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25619/discussion-between-barney-and-ramennoodles)